# How to create an element and use its ref to append child elements in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a html element on a parent component on react and access that component div inside a child component, then I can append new elements in the div from the child component.

After many attempts I wasn't able to fix props.canvasDivElement.current = null on the child constructor.

I've tried to do this using REF and without refs... No luck so far.

Any ideas?

The parent component looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactViewer from "../ReactViewer/ReactViewer";

export default class CanvasWrapper extends React.Component {
    private _divElement: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this._divElement = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ReactViewer canvasDivElement={this._divElement}></ReactViewer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The child component:

```
import React from "react";

type ReactViewerState = {
};

type ReactViewerProps = {
    canvasDivElement: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;

};

    export default class ReactViewer extends React.Component<ReactViewerProps, ReactViewerState> {
        constructor(props: ReactViewerProps, state: ReactViewerState) {
            super(props, state);
            const newElement = document.createElement('span');
            newElement.innerText = 'element';
            props.canvasDivElement.current!.appendChild(newElement); //current is null
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div ref={this.props.canvasDivElement} />
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I'm trying to create a div element on a parent component on react and acess that component div inside a child component, then I can append new elements in the div from the child component." This sounds like you are trying to solve a problem in React by circumventing the basic principles of React. You might as well just do this in vanilla JS instead. In React, the parent should be responsible for rendering its own children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rookie mistake, the element will always be null until it renders.
I've changed the line bellow to the componentDidMount event:

```
    props.canvasDivElement.current!.appendChild(newElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to circumvent the basic principles of React to solve a problem that React provides other tools for. The React way of communicating between a child and a parent is to pass a callback function to the child. Then the child calls the callback to signal to the parent to update its children.

Comment: As far as I know, to create that callback you would use REFs...
I was following this https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html


I would appreciate if you could send me any reference of what you are talking about, so that I can try it. 

Please read the following extracted from the react documentation:

"Note
The examples below have been updated to use the React.createRef() API introduced in React 16.3. If you are using an earlier release of React, we recommend using callback refs instead."



Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @GabrielMarcondes I think you need to take a step back from the current problem. Describe what you are trying to accomplish here. You can do that by filling in the blanks in this statement: "As a user, when I ... then I expect to see ...". In other words, describe what the user interaction with your app will be. From there we can help you find a solution to accomplish it.